Problema con Append y focusout
Estoy haciendo una prueba con algo muy basico, estoy creando un imput dinamico con un botton de agregar. al momento de crear el imput con append uso el focusout para hacer una alerta, todo funciona bien con el primer imput agregado, pero cuando agrego el segundo imput al momento de hacerle click nuevamente en el primer imput me arroja 2 alert al mismo tiempo y en el segundo imput solo uno, Si agrego 3 input me arroja 3 veces alert con el primer imput y asi susesivamente.
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="agregar" class="btn btn-success">ADD</button>
   <div class="add_input">
   <div/>
</div>

Jquery
$('#agregar').on('click',function(){
   $('.add_input').append('<input type="text" id="hello" class="test">');
  
     $('.test').on('focusout',function(){
      alert('hello');
     })
 })


Todo elemento puede tener múltiples eventos asociados, y estos eventos pueden repetirse, entonces cuando tú haces:
$('.test').on('focusout',function(){
   alert('hello');
})

Agregas el evento focusout a TODOS los elementos cuya clase es .test, entonces lo que te pasa es:

Comienzas sin input
Agregas el input 1
Agregas el evento focusout al input 1
Agregas el input 2
Agregas nuevamente el evento focusout al input 1 (queda con 2 eventos) y uno evento al input 2
Agregas el input 3
Agregas nuevamente el evento focusout al input 1 (queda con 3 eventos), agregas otro evento al input 2 (queda con 2) y agregas uno a input 3
Y así sucesivamente

Lo que puedes hacer, es agregar solo el evento al último que has agregado, para esto lo individualizas de esta manera:


$('#agregar').on('click', function() {
  //creo UN elemento, y queda individualizado
  const input = $('<input type="text" class="test">');
  
  //lo agrego
  $('.add_input').append(input);

  //Solo a ese elemento le añado el evento
  input.on('focusout', () => console.log("hola"));
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="agregar" class="btn btn-success">ADD</button>
  <div class="add_input">
    <div/>
  </div>



